# Bash script: array elements containing space character

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, whitespace

I'm getting started with bash scripting. I'm working with array elements that contain space characters. In the code below, the third array element is "Accessory Engine". I tried to set the space character using the `\` symbol, but this doesn't help.

In the larger routine (not included here), I use the array elements to automatize some stuff with command line tools. Those command line tools would accept "Accessory Engine" as an input.

```
#!/bin/bash
components="Persistence Instrument Accessory\Engine"
for i in $components; do
  echo ${i}
done
```

Now the output from this code is:

```
  Persistence
  Instrument
  Accessory\Engine
```

But I want it to be:

```
  Persistence
  Instrument
  Accessory Engine
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are defined differently:

```
components=(Persistence Instrument "Accessory Engine")
```

or

```
components=(Persistence Instrument Accessory\ Engine)
```

And accessed differently:

```
for i in "${components[@]}"
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I've tried both, but I still get the same issue:

    #!/bin/bash
    components=(one two three\ four)
    for i in ${components[@]}; do echo $i; done

Comment: thanks, the last comment fixed it. why do I have to include the " characters in the for loop?

Comment: @lomppi: Quotes are used to prevent unwanted word splitting. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting

Comment: @lomppi It is not relevant for this problem (but if there are two or more successive spaces) but in general you should get used to using quotes: `echo "${i}"`